# PasswordResetView: context variable protocol return http instead of https

Tags: django, django-registration

I use Django registration module in one of my app
stack : django/postgresql/docker

I override password reset view:

```
class ResetPasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetView):

    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_form.html'
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_message = "We've emailed you instructions for setting your password, " \
                      "if an account exists with the email you entered. You should receive them shortly." \
                      " If you don't receive an email, " \
                      "please make sure you've entered the address you registered with, and check your spam folder."
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

and following template for reset password:

```
Someone asked for password reset for email {{ email }}. 
Follow the link below:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

PS : Please do not reply to this email
```

but email template context protocol return http instead of https

what's wrong?

Comment: That is because the given request is not secure: https://github.com/django/django/blob/08688bd7dd8dfa218ecff03d6c94a753b1be8e59/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L246 it thus uses `https` if the request to trigger the view was secure and `http` otherwise.

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem so we don't have to worry about protocol it will automatically set `http` or `https` based on `"use_https"` value am I correct?

Comment: It will use http in case the *request* was http, and https if the *request* was made with a https request.

Comment: thanks for replying. url is an https://... so it should return https as it dose for most of my project but it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

You can build your url inside the **View**, in the **[`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)** method and use [**`request.build_absolute_uri()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)